# Nodejs post base64 string as form data

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

I am currently receiving a file encoded as a base64 string as part of a json payload:

```
{
    "file":"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPGRlZmluaXRpb25zIHhtb..."
}
```

With that string I am supposed to post the file as multipart/form-data to a different service so I have a method like this (using [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request)):

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var importFile = function(fileBase64Encoded, cb) {
    var decodedFile = new Buffer(fileBase64Encoded, 'base64');
    var r = request.post('http://localhost:8888/upload', function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, body);
    });
    var form = r.form();
    form.append('file', decodedFile);
}
```

And this is currently not working.
If I write file to disk and read it from there like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var importFile function(fileBase64Encoded, cb) {

    var decodedFile = new Buffer(fileBase64Encoded, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile('temp.txt', decodedFile, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        var r = request.post('http://localhost:8888/upload', function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
            }
            cb(null, body);
        })
        var form = r.form();
        form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('temp.txt'));
    });

}
```

Then it works...so Is there a real way to pass the base64 string as a valid parameter to the form? (right now trying with a buffer and not working)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that `http://localhost:8888/upload` is expecting `file` to be ... a "file". When you pass a file stream to `form.append()` it already knows it's a "file". When passing a `Buffer` it does not.

You can, however, tell `form.append()` to interpret your `Buffer` as a "file" by passing an options object as the third argument. The options object should have a key called `filename` containing a string with the name of the file. Optionally, the object can also include a `contentType` string and `knownLength` integer. If `contentType` is not included, `form.append()` will try to derive the content-type from the `filename`.

Other than to determine `contentType` (when it is not explicitly passed in the options argument), the `filename` you specify is irrelevant (i.e. you can use whatever file name you want). Unless, of course, you intend to use the `filename` on the server-side code.

In your case, the following should work.

```
var importFile = function(fileBase64Encoded, cb) {
    var decodedFile = new Buffer(fileBase64Encoded, 'base64');
    var r = request.post('http://localhost:8888/upload', function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, body);
    });
    var form = r.form();
    form.append('file', decodedFile, { filename: 'temp.txt' });
}
```

Comment: When you are calling request.post(), is the post request already fired? How do you fire it after appending?

Comment: @Sisir ...  `request.post()` fires automatically during the next cycle of the event loop. Any changes to `r` (the request object) will can be done before the next cycle is triggered.